# Need help on implementing a RADIUS client on Android

Tags: android, dependencies, radius

I am trying to implement a RADIUS client on Android; however, I have hit a show-stopper.  I'd greatly appreciate any advise or pointers that you could pass along.  I am using jradius-core-1.1.4.jar in my project, and it has a dependency on beans.BeanInfo, beans.Introspector, and beans.PropertyInspector; and they have a long list of dependency of other packages.  So, can anyone tell me the best way to resolve this.  FYI: I using Eclipse to build.  Just for the sake of keeping things simple, I hope I can stay that way.

Thank you so much.

skwok

Update:
11/2/2011 I have looked at http://code.google.com/p/dalvik/wiki/JavaxPackages.  It is a very attractive method, but I am afraid it won't work in this scenario.  It is because I am using the package indirectly.

Comment: And your question is? If you want help with the exceptions then you should post them...

Answer (score 0):

I have worked around the problem by using TinyRADIUS.  (Thanks, David.)